# Edit Smartobject in current window

Tags: adobe-photoshop, smartobject

Is it possible to edit the contents of a smart object without opening it in a new window? I need to be able to edit it as if it were a regular layer in my project, instead of having to edit it separately and then return to what I was doing.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately and as far as I'm concerned: No.

Smart objects are the equivalent of a file that can open in Photoshop or Illustrator. They are always opened as a new document.

As a temporary fix, if your object is not too big and you are only using it once, you can drag the layers to the document, edit them and turn them into a smart object again.

Comment: Thanks. The problem with dragging the layers back into the document is that you have to reposition them every time which can be a problem. Also if you are working with a scaled object and you are using smartobjects for lossless scaling, this will not be possible at all.

Comment: You don't have to drag them back in. Simply save and close them and your main file should update them accordingly.